# Understanding chemical kinetics

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics

> For a chemical reaction
>
> $$\ce{2 A + 2 B -> C + D}$$
>
> the order of reaction is one with respect to $\ce{A}$ and one with respect to $\ce{B}$. The initial rate of the reaction is $\pu{4e-2 mol L-1 s-1}.$ When $50\%$ of the reactants are converted into products, the rate of the reaction would become
>
> (**A**) $\pu{2e-2 mol L-1 s-1}$
> (**B**) $\pu{1e-2 mol L-1 s-1}$
> (**C**) $\pu{4e-2 mol L-1 s-1}$
> (**D**) $\pu{2e-1 mol L-1 s-1}$

This is the first time I am attempting kinetics problems. Is the question asking the concentration when the system has reached its half-life?

Could I use the half-life formula here?

My attempt at a solution:

I used the rate law which I equated to the definition of rate.

I have serious conceptual issues which I hope to clear up. So is this this right?

$$\frac{1}{c(t)} - \frac{1}{c_0}  = kt$$

Would this formula solve the above problem?

Answer (score 3):

> Is this the right formula to use to solve the above problem

Yes, this is it, if the initial concentrations of the reagents are the same (which is *not* mentioned explicitly in the problem statement, but probably is implied, because otherwise the problem would be unsolvable.)

Indeed, as A and B are spent in equal amounts, their concentrations are bound to be the same not only initially, but at all times: $[\ce{A}]=[\ce{B}]=c(t)$. Therefore $\dot c=-k\cdot[\ce{A}]\cdot[\ce{B}]=-k\cdot c^2$, which you seem to already know how to solve.

**Update.** Come to think of it, you don't actually need to solve for $c(t)$. You know that the rate is proportional to the first power of $[\ce{A}]$, and also to the first power of $[\ce{B}]$, and that both $[\ce{A}]$ and $[\ce{B}]$ have decreased by 50%; what would happen to the rate?

The concept of half life does not apply here, since the decay is not exponential.

Also, welcome to Chem.SE, and pay attention to the [formatting](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here).

Comment: Is the answer    $ 1 * 10^{-2}$

Comment: Looks like so. The concentrations decrease by 50%, and the rate depends on $c^2$, so it must have become 4 times lower.